# How do I add a / Page to HTML?

Tags: html

Every time I try to add a page, (e.g website.com/overflow.html) I want to add a / page. (e.g website.com/overflow. How do I do that?

I tried making a folder and adding index.html to it, it didn't work. (e.g folder/index.html)

(This is github pages)

Comment: I tried that rick.

Comment: my website, my bad for not clarifying.

Comment: if you are using any local server such as xampp/wamp you can do this with hep of .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

you have to configure the daemon that is your http server (nginx, apache, iis) to defaultly use index.html and then you can create a folder called `overflow` and inside of it put `index.html` otherwise you can use routes either inside the daemon config or with something like PHP or some other kind of Server Side Includes.

Comment: I'm using Github Pages with HTTPS. The index.html page for the website is there. so do i still do the index.html method?